# How to get child-parent relationship from set of edges

Tags: python, dictionary, binary-tree

I am working with a graph which is given to have a tree structure. I am trying to map a set of edges of a graph to parent-child relationships. I am using python dictionary to store the relationships. Let me illustrate with a example. Suppose I have a graph with 5 nodes and edges given are:

```
2 1
3 1
4 2
5 2
```

Code:

```
paths = {}
n = int(raw_input())      ##number of nodes
j = 1
while j < n:
    u, v = raw_input().split(" ")
    paths[int(v)] = int(u)
    j += 1
```

So my dictionary would be `{2:1, 3:1, 4:2, 5:2}`.

But the code will fail if the edges are given in the reverse order:

```
1 2
1 3
2 4
2 5
```

In this case my dictionary would be `{1:3, 2:5}` and I have missed two edges.

How can I make code more robust?

**EDIT:** For each edge, I need to be able to tell which node is child and which node is parent

Comment: How do you know which node is the root? Without that, it's meaningless to talk about parent/child

Comment: Unless your graph is directed and loop free (DAG), you cannot have a meaningful child-parent relationship

Comment: @gnibbler: Root node is not given. But still, if you plot the graph with the given edges then you'll find that 1 is actually the root node.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: Graph is given to be un-directed and loop free. Intuitively, we should be able to find root and hence the parent-child relations. The question boils down to how to find the root.

Comment: @gnibbler. I got your point, you are right!!

Answer (score 0):

When you use a dictionary the following way:.

```
paths[int(v)] = int(u)
```

You just reassign a value pointed by a key instead of adding it to a list.

If I understand you correctly, you should use the following:

```
paths = []
n = int(raw_input())      ##number of nodes
j = 1
while j < n:
    u, v = raw_input().split(" ")
    paths.append(int(u), int(v))
    j += 1
```

It at least doesn't depend on input order.